# How to charge powerbank properly?

Tags: power-supply

I have bought a power bank Viking QC 3.0. There are two ports for input. USB C and micro USB. How do I charge this power bank properly? Can I use both inputs at one time? (2 electric power sources, both inputs). 
Or is it better to use just one input at one time to charge? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you got a user manual? What does it say?

Comment: Yes I have the user manual, but it is so simple and shows absolutely nothing useful, just images. And I have not found better one on the Internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don’t use them in parallel.
If you do you might fry the power bank if you’re lucky. If you are not lucky you’ve got a fire.

Those inputs are to be used one at a time.
The powerbank just provides two ports with different connectors for convenience  so you have more options which cable to use.
Additionally the USB-C port might allow for faster charging but that depends on both the circuitry in the powerbank and a compatible power source.

EDIT: As Albin pointed out in the comments some power banks do allow for this dual input operation, but those are very rare.
If it isn’t explicitly stated in the manual this is safe don’t try it. Better be safe than sorry.

Comment: My power bank (it's not the same model) can use both charging ports at the same time, but it states it in the user manual. If you are unsure and don't want to risk his scenarios go with Tonny's answer!!! I just want to point out: this answer is not universal.

Comment: @albin I know they exist allthough I never encountered one myself. But in 99 of a 100 cases it can’t do dual inputs, so better be safe than sorry. I will edit this in my answer in case the comments get deleted at some point.